# Automount Windows shares on Ubuntu 18.04 using a Kerberos ticket

Tags: ubuntu, mount, network-shares, active-directory, cifs

I've been struggling with this for a few days now. I'm trying to integrate a Ubuntu 18.04 workstation in a network that is mainly Windows. Authentication is done by Active Directory on a server running Windows Server 2012.
I managed to join the domain without too many problems.
The next thing I want to do is mount automatically a Windows share for the Linux user. I got it working by adding this line to /etc/auto.master:

```
/mnt/cifs /etc/auto.cifs --timeout=60 --ghost
```

and this in /etc/auto.cifs:

```
NameOfTheShare -fstype=cifs,uid=$UID,gid=100,username=&,credentials=$HOME/.smbcredentials ://ServerName/NameOfTheShare
```

Now, I'm not comfortable with the idea of having user passwords in plain text in a file. Plus I read somewhere that it was possible to use the Kerberos ticket to mount a CIFS share. So I tried to put this in auto.cifs instead:

```
NameOfTheShare -fstype=cifs,sec=krb5,username=&,domain=mydomain.local,multiuser,cruid=${UID} ://ServerName/NameOfTheShare
```

(This is a file that works fine on CentOS 7).

As it didn't work, I decided to look for traces of automount errors. Apparently, the only way to achieve that is to stop the autofs service and run automount in the foreground with the verbose option on:

```
$ sudo service autofs stop
$ sudo automount -f -v
```

Now, when I `cd` into `/mnt/cifs/NameOfTheShare`, the share is mounted as expected (so I can't debug anything!)

If I kill automount, unmount the share manually and relaunch autofs.service, the initial problem comes back: `/mnt/cifs/NameOfTheShare` can't be mounted.

What is the difference between having the autofs service running and having launched automount manually that can explain that the first method fails when the second succeeds?

Subsidiary question: isn't there an error log of the autofs service somewhere? I couldn't find any. Even journalctl doesn't give any valuable info.

Edit:

Here is the output of `klist`:

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1072801131_l33ZzG
Default principal: MyLogin@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
31/08/2018 15:11:10  01/09/2018 01:11:10  krbtgt/MYDOMAIN.LOCAL@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL
        renew until 01/09/2018 15:11:10
```

Edit 2:

I managed to find more info on the automount error. Syslog shows this message:

```
No credentials cache found (filename: /tmp/krb5cc_1072801131_igAxKm)
```

However, `klist` now gives me:

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1072801131_zgYtQf
```

It looks like automount is looking for the wrong credentials cache file name. The problem is, I've got no idea about how to fix that.

Comment: Does your auto.cifs file contain the literal text `uid=$UID`, `cruid=${UID}` and so on, or does it have actual numbers as the value?

Comment: @grawity Yes, it does contain literal text `uid=$UID` and `cruid=${UID}`.

Comment: What Kerberos credential cache type do you use according to `klist`? (FILE, DIR, KEYRING, etc.)?

Comment: @grawity: I edited my question to answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. Put something like this into the krb5.conf and it works with pam_krb5.

```
[appdefaults]
forwardable = true  
pam = {  
    minimum_uid = 1000  
    ccache=FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_%u  
    YOUR.REALM = {  
        ignore_k5login = true  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use libpam-krb5 ? If yes, rename krb5cc_1072801131_zgYtQf to krbcc5cc_1072801131 and check it again. It looks like cifs.upcall needs something like FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_(UID). Remove libpam-krb5 and it should work.